# How to pull the data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a User class which have the method to login, logout, register, etc.

I have the userid saved in a Session.

Now, I am wondering how I should grab the data from the database - the best way. Should I pull all data in each site load and store in a class. or should i have some method in my User class that I can call like get_data(email, userid) and then I will receive the email. What is the best method to do this?

Cheers.

Comment: Why not only pull the user as required. The latter option.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way is to write a constructor for User class with argument `$user_id` and this constructor should will all necessary information about current user. And then you should create methods what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Within your User class store the userid once a user has logged in.

Internally you could create a private method get_data('email') which in turn uses the locally stored userid.  You could further expose this by creating public methods i.e. User.getEmail()

This in turn means that the setting and unsetting of userID internally is handled by your login/logout methods only thus preventing a user requesting someone elses data whilst still being flexible enough to expose data to the class as required.

I would not grab all data at point of login as chances are a lot of it will not be required.  If any piece(s) of data are ALWAYS going to be required, then I would grab those pieces of data at login (i.e. a username).  If a piece of data is more likely to be not needed then I would not grab it at point of login.  At the end of the day this is a judgement call that you'll have to make based on your application though.

I hope this is of help.

Answer (score 0):

I have made very good experience, with loading the full user object from database on LOGIN and then storing this object in the session.